# POST to curl and set an empty array

Tags: arrays, post, curl

From the command line, I'm trying to send POST data via `curl` and am having trouble assigning an empty array.

Example:

```
curl -X POST -d "customer[name]=Wes&customer[friends]=[]"
```

When the request runs, the parameters are seeing "[]" as a string instead of an empty array. The same goes for when I try to assign values to it: `=[1,2,3]` turns into `"[1,2,3]"`

I found similar questions like this on SO, but they all regard using PHP's curl library.

Answer (score 1):

If send:

```
curl -X POST -d "customer[name]=Wes&customer[friends][]="
```

`customer[friends][]=` will not be an empty array, but an array with the first element with value `''` (empty string)

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, here is the solution.

To pass an empty array through curl, do the following:

```
curl -X POST -d "customer[name]=Wes&customer[friends][]="
```

Notice that `customer[friends][]`, which would be the first entry in the array, is left blank in the params.

To pass values `[1,2,3]` into the array, do the following:

```
curl -X POST -d "customer[name]=Wes&customer[friends][]=1&customer[friends][]=2&customer[friends][]=3"
```

Now, `friends` holds `["1","2","3"]`